# Irradiance volume Light leaks

Tags: lighting

I've got a scene, I am using the Irradiance volume to assist me with lighting but it is causing light leaks at the top corners of the room, I have tried making the walls thicker, I've also tried increasing the resolution of the irradiance volume...
Does anyone know of a workaround? I'm using blender 2.8 at the moment.

Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: Have same issue. Any advices?